# $E[W\otimes W]$ for Wishart R.V. $W$

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, wishart-distribution

What is the value of $E[W\otimes W]$ for Wishart R.V. $W$?

$\otimes$ refers to Kronecker product

I found related formula for $E[WAW]$ on page 467 of Seber's Matrix [handbook](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9780470226797), wondering if $E[W\otimes W]$ can be extracted from it.

[image]

Comment: equation 9: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2212.01412.pdf This also confirms the formula correction stated below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that there is an error in Seber's formula and the correct form is
$$
\mathbf{E}(WAW)
= m[\Sigma A \Sigma + \mathrm{Tr}(A\Sigma) \Sigma] + m^2 \Sigma A \Sigma
$$
(try this and the orgiginal formula with $m = d = 1$).

Then, we can use the vec-trick to write, for any $A$,
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}(W \otimes W) \mathrm{vec}(A)
&= \mathrm{vec}\{\mathbf{E}(W A W)\} \\
&= m(m+1) \mathrm{vec}(\Sigma A \Sigma) + m\mathrm{Tr}(A\Sigma) \mathrm{vec},(\Sigma).
\end{align*}
where we repeatedly commute the expectation with the $\mathrm{vec}$, since it is a linear operator.

But recall that $\mathrm{Tr}(A^{\mathrm{T}}B) = \mathrm{vec}(A)^{\mathrm{T}}\mathrm{vec}(B)$.
Using this and the vec-trick again we have that
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}(W \otimes W) \mathrm{vec}(A)
&= m(m+1) (\Sigma \otimes \Sigma) \mathrm{vec}(A) + m (\mathrm{vec}(\Sigma)^{\mathrm{T}} \mathrm{vec}(A) )\mathrm{vec}(\Sigma) \\
&= \{m(m+1) (\Sigma \otimes \Sigma) + m \mathrm{vec}(\Sigma)\mathrm{vec}(\Sigma)^{\mathrm{T}}\} \mathrm{vec}(A).
\end{align*}

SInce this holds for any $A$, we conclude that
$$
\mathbf{E}(W \otimes W)
= m(m+1) (\Sigma \otimes \Sigma) + m \mathrm{vec}(\Sigma)\mathrm{vec}(\Sigma)^{\mathrm{T}}.
$$

Comment: `\mathrm{vec}` does not yield context-dependent horizontal spacing the way `\operatorname{vec}` does. That is why you see $m\mathrm{vec}(\Sigma)$ rather than $m\operatorname{vec}(\Sigma).$